# Convert iterator of Result to Result<Vec<_>>

Tags: rust

How can I transform an `iterator` of `Result` into a `Result` of a vector?

As an example, suppose I want to transform the `Bytes` iterator obtainable from the `Read` trait:

```
use std::io::{Read, Result};

use std::fs::File;


fn main() {
    let f = File::open("some-file").unwrap();
    let bytes = f.bytes();

    let byte_vector: Result<Vec<u8>> = read_bytes(bytes);
}

fn read_bytes<I: Iterator<Item=Result<u8>>>(bytes: I) -> Result<Vec<u8>> {
    unimplemented!();
}
```